# ggplot colour matching from two different data sets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data in the following format, called `data_1` (train data) and `data_2` (test data). They both consist of 200 observations.

I am trying to plot the data and match the colours from one graph to the next. So that I can see which training line matches the testing line. In the end I will use a `grid.arrange` to see the plots side by side and I think it will be useful to see which training lines match the testing lines. `grid.arrange(data_1, data_2, ncol=2)`.

```
ggplot(data_1, aes(ID)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = value, colour = trainauc)) +
  theme(legend.position="none")

ggplot(data_2, aes(ID)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = value, colour = testauc)) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

In order to try and match the plot colours, I have some data in this format (which is a ´data.frame´ not a matrix).

```
matching <- matrix(
  c(0.9497, 0.9579, 0.8838, 0.8896),
  nrow = 2,
  ncol = 2)
```

The values in the `data.frame` called `matching` are just the values in `data_1` and `data_2` at every sequence of 100 (which is the final value for each plot), but (in my data) the data is not ordered, so I am trying to match them together. So the line with a terminal value (at seq 100) of `0.9497` in data_1 will be the same colour as the corresponding plot of `data_2` with a terminal value of `0.8838`. They can be matched using the rows in the `data.frame`.

Hopefully its a little clear what I am trying to do.

data_1

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
    11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
    24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
    37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
    50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
    63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 
    76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 
    89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
    28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
    41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 
    54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 
    67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 
    80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 
    93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L), trainauc = c("AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", "AUC.score.0.9497.4", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", "AUC.score.0.9579.1", 
    "AUC.score.0.9579.1"), value = c(0.8403, 0.8755, 0.8899, 0.8967, 
    0.9014, 0.9048, 0.907, 0.9089, 0.9106, 0.9121, 0.913, 0.9143, 
    0.9154, 0.9163, 0.9171, 0.9181, 0.919, 0.9199, 0.9207, 0.9214, 
    0.9222, 0.9229, 0.9232, 0.9237, 0.9242, 0.9247, 0.9253, 0.9257, 
    0.9262, 0.9269, 0.9271, 0.9277, 0.9282, 0.9287, 0.929, 0.9296, 
    0.9301, 0.9307, 0.9311, 0.9316, 0.932, 0.9322, 0.9328, 0.9332, 
    0.9337, 0.934, 0.9344, 0.9346, 0.935, 0.9353, 0.9356, 0.9359, 
    0.9363, 0.9367, 0.9371, 0.9373, 0.9378, 0.9382, 0.9385, 0.9388, 
    0.9391, 0.9394, 0.9397, 0.9399, 0.9402, 0.9406, 0.9408, 0.9411, 
    0.9414, 0.9417, 0.942, 0.9423, 0.9427, 0.9429, 0.9432, 0.9434, 
    0.9436, 0.944, 0.9443, 0.9446, 0.9449, 0.9451, 0.9453, 0.9455, 
    0.9459, 0.9461, 0.9463, 0.9466, 0.9468, 0.9471, 0.9474, 0.9475, 
    0.9479, 0.9481, 0.9484, 0.9486, 0.9488, 0.9491, 0.9494, 0.9497, 
    0.843, 0.8801, 0.89, 0.8968, 0.9016, 0.9051, 0.9078, 0.9098, 
    0.9116, 0.9132, 0.9147, 0.9159, 0.917, 0.9182, 0.9195, 0.9205, 
    0.9212, 0.9221, 0.923, 0.9239, 0.9246, 0.9255, 0.9261, 0.9268, 
    0.9275, 0.9282, 0.929, 0.9297, 0.9303, 0.9309, 0.9315, 0.9321, 
    0.9326, 0.9332, 0.9337, 0.9341, 0.9346, 0.9351, 0.9355, 0.936, 
    0.9364, 0.937, 0.9375, 0.938, 0.9384, 0.9389, 0.9394, 0.9398, 
    0.9402, 0.9406, 0.9411, 0.9416, 0.9419, 0.9423, 0.9428, 0.9432, 
    0.9436, 0.944, 0.9444, 0.9448, 0.9453, 0.9457, 0.946, 0.9464, 
    0.9468, 0.9471, 0.9474, 0.9479, 0.9482, 0.9485, 0.9489, 0.9493, 
    0.9497, 0.95, 0.9504, 0.9507, 0.951, 0.9513, 0.9516, 0.9519, 
    0.9522, 0.9525, 0.9529, 0.9533, 0.9535, 0.9538, 0.9541, 0.9544, 
    0.9548, 0.955, 0.9553, 0.9556, 0.9559, 0.9563, 0.9566, 0.9568, 
    0.9571, 0.9571, 0.9576, 0.9579)), .Names = c("ID", "trainauc", 
    "value"), row.names = 28801:29000, class = "data.frame")
```

data_2

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 
76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 
89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 
54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 
67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 
80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 
93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L), testauc = c("AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", 
"AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8838", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", 
"AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896", "AUC.score.0.8896"), 
    value = c(0.834, 0.868, 0.8812, 0.8871, 0.8902, 0.8927, 0.8943, 
    0.895, 0.8963, 0.897, 0.8965, 0.897, 0.8979, 0.8983, 0.8982, 
    0.8983, 0.8982, 0.8981, 0.898, 0.8979, 0.8979, 0.8976, 0.8971, 
    0.8971, 0.897, 0.8964, 0.8963, 0.8961, 0.8963, 0.8956, 0.8942, 
    0.8948, 0.8948, 0.8943, 0.8942, 0.8942, 0.8941, 0.8942, 0.8935, 
    0.8935, 0.8937, 0.8928, 0.8928, 0.8929, 0.8933, 0.8931, 0.8936, 
    0.8934, 0.8932, 0.8927, 0.8922, 0.8919, 0.8917, 0.8918, 0.8913, 
    0.8915, 0.8914, 0.8912, 0.8909, 0.8906, 0.8903, 0.89, 0.8903, 
    0.8902, 0.8898, 0.8898, 0.8893, 0.8895, 0.8893, 0.8894, 0.8893, 
    0.8888, 0.8884, 0.8878, 0.8876, 0.8874, 0.8871, 0.8871, 0.8874, 
    0.8871, 0.8869, 0.887, 0.8868, 0.8862, 0.8863, 0.8861, 0.8857, 
    0.8853, 0.885, 0.8849, 0.8854, 0.8847, 0.885, 0.8848, 0.8847, 
    0.8844, 0.8841, 0.8842, 0.884, 0.8838, 0.8377, 0.8733, 0.8844, 
    0.8901, 0.8929, 0.8953, 0.8971, 0.8978, 0.8983, 0.8982, 0.8992, 
    0.8995, 0.899, 0.8988, 0.899, 0.8987, 0.8986, 0.8987, 0.8984, 
    0.8987, 0.8985, 0.8987, 0.8983, 0.898, 0.8982, 0.8984, 0.8982, 
    0.8982, 0.898, 0.8982, 0.8982, 0.8981, 0.8977, 0.8978, 0.8974, 
    0.8976, 0.8976, 0.897, 0.8968, 0.8966, 0.8965, 0.8962, 0.8961, 
    0.896, 0.8958, 0.8954, 0.8956, 0.8953, 0.8951, 0.8951, 0.895, 
    0.8948, 0.8946, 0.8949, 0.895, 0.8948, 0.8948, 0.8948, 0.8946, 
    0.8946, 0.8943, 0.8943, 0.8943, 0.894, 0.8937, 0.8936, 0.8932, 
    0.8932, 0.8928, 0.8927, 0.8926, 0.8925, 0.8924, 0.8921, 0.8919, 
    0.8919, 0.8915, 0.8914, 0.8913, 0.8913, 0.8915, 0.8914, 0.8914, 
    0.891, 0.8912, 0.891, 0.8908, 0.8911, 0.8913, 0.8912, 0.891, 
    0.8909, 0.8908, 0.8906, 0.8901, 0.8899, 0.89, 0.8894, 0.8897, 
    0.8896)), .Names = c("ID", "testauc", "value"), row.names = 28801:29000, class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT: These are the plots I am getting when applied to the whole data. I have these same grpahs plotted (without matching the correct colours) and it looks the same, its just the horizontal lines which do not make sense.
[image]

EDIT 2: This was the original plots that I created, without the correct colours. 
[image]

EDIT 3: Here is some code I followed.

```
matching <- as.data.frame(matching) %>%
  mutate(group_id = rownames(.)) %>%
  gather(-group_id, key = key, value = group) %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  mutate(group = as.character(group * 10000))

matching <- matching[!matching$group == 10000, ]

data_1 <- left_join(data_1, matching)
data_2 <- left_join(data_2, matching)

train_auc <- ggplot(data_1, aes(ID)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = value, colour = factor(group_id))) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
train_auc

test_auc <- ggplot(data_2, aes(ID)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = value, colour = factor(group_id))) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
test_auc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem seems to be this. We have a matrix that looks like

```
head(matching, 3)
#       V1     V2
# 1 0.9241 0.9111
# 2 0.9237 0.9106
# 3 0.9247 0.9110
```

and we would like it to look like

```
                V1               V2
1 AUC.score.0.9241 AUC.score.0.9111
2 AUC.score.0.9237 AUC.score.0.9106
3 AUC.score.0.9247  AUC.score.0.911
```

while taking into account repeats (so we might have `AUC.score.0.9241`, `AUC.score.0.9241.1`, `AUC.score.0.9241.2`, etc.).

The main strategy is to use `split` and `lapply`. First do the left column:

```
matching <- as.data.frame(matching)
match_list <- split(matching, matching$V1)
match_out <- lapply(match_list, function(x) {
    x$V1 <- paste("AUC.score", x$V1, 0:(nrow(x) - 1), sep = ".")
    x
})
match_out <- do.call(rbind, match_out)
match_out$V1 <- gsub("\\.0$", "", match_out$V1)
```

Then the right column:

```
match_list <- split(match_out, match_out$V2)
match_out <- lapply(match_list, function(x) {
    x$V2 <- paste("AUC.score", x$V2, 0:(nrow(x) - 1), sep = ".")
    x
})
match_out <- do.call(rbind, match_out)
match_out$V2 <- gsub("\\.0$", "", match_out$V2)
```

We do some cleaning up, and append a column of group IDs:

```
rownames(match_out) <- NULL
match_out$group_id <- 1:nrow(match_out)
head(match_out)
#                   V1                 V2 group_id
# 1 AUC.score.0.9999.4   AUC.score.0.8493        1
# 2      AUC.score.1.8   AUC.score.0.8495        2
# 3 AUC.score.0.9999.3   AUC.score.0.8506        3
# 4   AUC.score.0.9999   AUC.score.0.8508        4
# 5      AUC.score.1.6 AUC.score.0.8508.1        5
# 6      AUC.score.1.2   AUC.score.0.8515        6
```

Now, we merge this data frame with `data_1` and `data_2`:

```
# Merge
library(dplyr)
data_1 <- left_join(data_1, select(match_out, trainauc = V1, group_id))
data_2 <- left_join(data_2, select(match_out, testauc = V2, group_id))
```

Plotting the results:

```
bind_rows(train = data_1, test = data_2, .id = "type") %>%
  ggplot(aes(ID)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = value, colour = factor(group_id))) +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  facet_wrap("type")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have been working through this on my own data and I am running into problems... It works perfectly when I follow through the "mini data" that I uploaded but when I apply it to the whole data I am getting (almost correct) plots. I think I have a problem with duplicate values. Can I upload a little more data and we work through it? Before I sent 2 data points, perhaps I upload the first 50?

Comment: I'm not sure SO is a good platform for posting large amounts of data. Perhaps post a Dropbox/Google Drive link to your data or a subset of it? Also see my edits to the original answer.

Comment: I have uploaded the documents to dropbox, but not sure how to publically make them available.

Comment: Let me know if you can access this: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6x65z90u8eevxdz/AADcAmjsB_gHIgT2PhDEXBJ9a?dl=0

Comment: I edited the original post showing the plots I am receiving, its almost working, but I am not sure why the horizontal lines appear.

Comment: Couple of problems, but the main one is that any given train AUC can map on to more than one test AUC. E.g. do `matching[matching[,1] == 0.9142, ]`. How do we know which train AUC matches which test AUC in this case?

Comment: I have re-uploaded the data to dropbox. The data I have at this moment has not been manipulated. So in the `matching` file the data is correct. That is in `data_1`under column `trainauc`  the result `AUC.score.0.9241` corresponds to the correct `testauc`.  It also makes sense to me also because if we look at row `432` of `matching` we get a train_auc `0.9999` and test_auc `0.8658` which tells me that the model has overfit.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The problem is this. `matching[matching[,1] == 0.9142, ]` (not `9241`) returns 5 rows.  So `0.9142` in `train` could match `0.9057` in `test`. It could also match `0.9062`. So, what should `"AUC.score.0.9142"` in `train` match to? What about `"AUC.score.0.9142.1"` and `"AUC.score.0.9142.2"`?

Comment: Yes, I ran into this problem. It is the same with `matching[matching[,1] == 1.000, ]` which returns `24` observations. The thing is, I do not (really) care about the group namings, so if there are `24` groups with `1.0000` that tells me that the `trainauc` overfit. In my plot (in the original edited question` I removed the observations with the same values for quick illustration. However, if observation `1.0000` for case 1 changes to `1.0001` and case 2 changes to `1.0002` ... case 24 `1.0024` then this is fine. If at the end we are just going to plot via a grouped name, it should not matter?

Comment: As far as I understand, as long as the values get plotted (which they do) it should not matter what the group name is called, since I use ` + theme(legend.position="none")` I do not report on the group names.

Comment: It's not simply a naming issue. E.g., try `filter(data_1, grepl("9142", trainauc)) %>% ggplot(aes(x = ID, y = value, colour = trainauc)) + geom_line()`. The AUC is the same for these five series, but they are five distinct lines. You seem to be saying that's not important to you. Is that right?

Comment: super appreciate your help thus far though!

Comment: I am following your method exactly and I am getting the exact same structure / results in the data, however the final plot still looks like my original plot with the horizontal lines. What version of ggplot are you using? I have ggplot2_2.2.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171008/discussion-between-weihuang-wong-and-user113156).